# Install the Google Play Services SDK issue

Tags: android, google-play-services, eclipse-adt

I would like to install Google Play Services and following this example: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

> Scroll to the bottom of the package list, expand Extras, select Google Play services, and install it. If you're using Android Studio, also install Google Repository (it provides the Maven repository used for Gradle builds).

But I didn't see Google Play services in the Extras folder... I have updated everything in Eclipse and SDK Manager to the latest version and there are nothing more to update. What should I do?

I am using Mac and Eclipse for my development.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll be able to see it in the 'extras' folder only after you install it using the SDK Manager. e.g. I don't have it installed on my system (as you can see from the image below), so if I navigate to my 'extras' folder, I won't see it there.

[image]

However, if you did install it from the SDK Manager, I would suggest you double-check the "SDK path" (at the top of the image above), since you might be looking in the incorrect location.

Comment: I did't see it at all in the SDK Manager - I need to install it (like in your case) from the SDK Manager, right? I didn't not see anything Google Play... in the Extras folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution... but it is weird. Go to the preference of SDK Manager, and switch on Force HTTPS option... and all the Google Play options appeared!